# make maven test goal fail when karate scenario fails

Tags: maven, karate

when running command 'mvn test' and there is failed scenarios Maven still reports the build is a success. how can you make the build fail when a scenario fails[mvn test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSZBQ.png)

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the test failure flag to false:

```
-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false
```

Comment: Hi @Pobu,

Thanks for your reply.

You command doesnt resolve my problem, please see the command that I have used below. The build succeeds event if there are Karate scenario failures.

`mvn test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false -Dtest=RunContractRedesign`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to my problem.

I used the run parallel technique instead of using the `Runwith`.